# How does glutaraldehyde kill bacteria?

Tags: pathology, death

How does glutaraldehyde kill bacteria?

After disinfecting, does it leave the corpses of the bacteria to count?

Does it leave bio-film in tact?

Comment: Modifies proteins by reacting at the amino group. Same what formalin does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gluteraldehyde interacts with [amino groups](http://publish.uwo.ca/~jkiernan/formglut.htm) to block the dynamic movements that biology requires.[image]

Yes the corpses of the fixed bacteria can be counted and bio-films will be intact but the bacteria will be fixed in place.

Biofilms that are fixed with g[luteraldehyde may shrink](http://amb-express.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13568-015-0097-4) when prepared for imaging due to the effects of dehydration.